# How to use tensorflow.distributions in a custom loss function for a keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For a Deep learning model I defined with tf2.0 keras I need to write a custom loss function.

As this will depend on stuff like entropy and normal log_prob, it would really make my life less misrable if I could use tf.distributions.Normal and use two model outpus as mu and sigma respectivly.

However, as soon as I put this into my loss function, I get the Keras error that no gradient is defined for this function.

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

I tried encalpsulating the call in a tf.contrib.eager.Variable as I read somewhere. Did not help.

What is the trick to use them? I don't see a reason from the fundamental arcitecture why I should not be able to use them in a mixed form.

```
#this is just an example which does not really give a meaningful result.
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as K
import numpy as np

def custom_loss_fkt(extra_output):
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=y_pred,scale=extra_output)
        d = dist.entropy()
        return K.backend.mean(d)
    return loss

input_node = K.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
dense = K.layers.Dense(8,activation='relu')(input_node)
#dense = K.layers.Dense(4,activation='relu')(dense)
out1 = K.layers.Dense(4,activation='linear')(dense)
out2 = K.layers.Dense(4,activation ='linear')(dense)
model = K.Model(inputs = input_node, outputs = [out1,out2])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = [custom_loss_fkt(out2),custom_loss_fkt(out1)])
model.summary()
x = np.zeros((1,1))
y1 = np.array([[0.,0.1,0.2,0.3]])
y2 = np.array([[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]])
model.fit(x,[y1,y2],epochs=1000,verbose=0)
print(model.predict(x))
```